# Android in Eclipse: Copy/Paste From LogCat (only "Text")

Tags: android, eclipse, logging

Is there a way to copy/paste from the Eclipse LogCat and ONLY copy/paste the "Text" that was logged?

Normally when I copy/paste from the LogCat, it copies everything, including "Level", "Time", "Application", "Tag", and "Text", when most of the time, the only thing I actually want is "Text".

This is an extreme annoyance, especially when copy/pasting multiple lines.

Comment: save you log from logcat then do what ever edit you want

Comment: It still saves the log with all those extra fields that would still have to be deleted if I only wanted the "Text" field's log information.

Comment: I think LogCat can be formatted in certain ways ([try here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)). But you will lose possibly important debug info.

Comment: you can put filter and then save it in file

Comment: Based on the comment by @MikeD, one way to do this would be to configure the LogCat via ADB using the following command: "adb logcat -v raw".  However, I'm looking for something a litte easier to accomplish that can be done from inside Eclipse, if possible...

Comment: @MikeS found something ?!!

Answer (score 4):

You can try the steps:

1. Right click on the part you want to copy
2. Click on find similar message here you will see "by log message option".

select those text you want to copy and paste where you want. (I tried it in windows).